# How to use wxsqlite3 secure in linux?

Tags: linux, sqlite, security, wxwidgets

I used `wxsqlite3` (version 3.11.1) to encrypt SQLite database on Windows OS. I simply included `sqlite3.h` and `sqlite3.lib` into my projects, and used `sqlite3_key` to encrypt my database. It works fine, but now I want to use `wxsqlite3` on  Linux (Centos 7).

I spent many days trying to compile but failed. How I can use the same methods as on Windows on Linux? Could anyone who has experience, share their knowledge and practice on how to compile SQLite and `wxSqlite3` in order to be able to access encryption functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There never existed a version 3.11.1 of wxSQLite3. However, there was a release of SQLite 3.11.1 in March 2016. Current version of SQLite is version 3.23.1.
2. wxSQLite3 is mainly a thin wrapper for the SQLite library for wxWidgets based applications. Are you developing a wxWidgets application? Or are/were you just using the SQLite library with encryption extension that is included in wxSQLite3?
3. Starting with wxSQLite3 version 3.5.0 the included build system was overhauled, making it easier to build wxSQLite3 under Windows and Linux. Up to version wxSQLite3 3.5.9 pre-generated build files were included for the wxWidgets wrapper library only, but a premake5 script for generating build files was included. Since version wxSQLite3 4.0.0 pre-generated build files are also included for the SQLite library with encryption extension.

So, my advice would be to download a recent version of wxSQLite3 and try the included build files for Linux (and other Linux-like systems).

Comment: Thanks.(1) It is my mistakes. I used wxsqlite3(3.3.1) in windows system. (2) And I just want to use the SQLite library with encryption extension that is included in wxSQLite3(no for wxWidgets application). (3) I download wxsqlite3(4) and in path "sqlite3secure" find makefile.am ,i just ./configure, make and make install ,it is success. and generate a file named "sqlite3shell", two problems: one is when i use sqlite3shell to  create a table test.db  and pragma rekey='password' , but when i try to use sqlite3shell(version 
 wxsqlite3.3.1) to open test.db and pragma key='password' ,it fails

Comment: it seemed incompatible with old version. and another question is in linux system how to compatible with my widnows code.my windows code like this: ret = sqlite3_open(dbname, &db);
 ret = sqlite3_key(db,"mypassword",10);
 sqlite3_close(db);
 db = 0;

Comment: E:\>sqlite3shell test.db
SQLite version 3.12.1 2016-04-08 15:09:49
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> pragma key='123';
sqlite> select * from a;
1|2
sqlite> .q

=test.db is same  ========================= E:\bin>sqlite3shell test.db
SQLite version 3.23.1 2018-04-10 17:39:29
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> pragma key='123';
sqlite> select * from a;
Error: unsupported file format
sqlite>

Comment: Until wxSQLite3 version 3.5.9 the default encryption scheme was "AES 128 Bit CBC". For wxSQLite3 version 4.0.0 and above the default encryption scheme is now "ChaCha20 - Poly1305". If you want to enable the old encryption scheme for compatibility reasons, you have to invoke configure with an additional parameter, namely "--enable-codec=aes128".

Comment: thanks for your kind answers. here is my steps: (in linux centos7) (1) tar -xzvf wxsqlite3-4.0.3.tar.gz  (2) cd /wxsqlite3-4.0.3/sqlite3secure (3) ./configure --enable-codec=aes128 (4) make  (5) make install.  success.  sqlite3shell can open test.db. now i try to program with c++ to open db and encryption. use IDE vs2017 . the main.cpp like this:       #include <cstdio>   #include <sqlite3.h> int main(){

Comment: You might want to use the header file "sqlite3secure.h" which adds definitions for the additional API functions of wxSQLite3. Don't forget to define at least the symbol SQLITE_HAS_CODEC (#define SQLITE_HAS_CODEC 1) to activate the encryption extension.

Comment: I copy all /sqlite3secure/src *.h files to my projects path
modify sqlite3secure.h as this:
#define SQLITE_HAS_CODEC 1
#include "sqlite3.h"
IDE vs2017 .
the main.cpp like this:
#include <cstdio>
#include "sqlite3secure.h"
int main()
{
sqlite3 *db = NULL;
int     ret = 0;
ret = sqlite3_open("test.db", &db);
ret = sqlite3_rekey(db,"123",3);
sqlite3_close(db);
 db = 0;
 return 0;
}
but when compile and linking objects ,errors appears :
sqlite3_open sqlite3_key, sqlite3_close undefined reference.
how i can run this simple program successed,
please give me some advice ,thanks

Comment: If you get undefined linker references, you most likely forgot to add a reference to the SQLite (link) library for the linker. You do this by selecting the properties of your project, and then select "Linker / Input" from the treeview, and add "sqlite3.lib" to "Additional dependencies".

Comment: as i mentioned above ,I use wxsqlite3 work fine in windows system.just include sqlite3.h and input sqlite.lib.run link sqlite3.dll. all success. but when my code transplant to linux sytem, problems appear,i use ide vs2017 for linux to edit and  run my program,as your advice, i include sqlite3secure.h ,but can not run ,errors appears :
sqlite3_open sqlite3_key, sqlite3_close undefined reference.can i input sqlite3.lib in linux system ?

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted "vs2017" as "build under Windows". Under Linux you will have to add "libsqlite3secure.la" (resulting from the build in folder "sqlite3secure" via configure) as linker input.

Comment: now I can run my program !!.by the way ,my step  is :add command line `pkg-config --cflags --libs sqlite3secure` instead of "inker input.libsqlite3secure.la" ,thanks a lot, give me a big help.